# Index match in query

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch

I'have a string and I'd like to search the longest match in this string with a table row value. In SQL this query works fine:

```
SELECT model, LENGTH(model) AS size 
FROM models 
WHERE 'Acer Aspire 3 A315-42' LIKE CONCAT('%', model, '%') 
ORDER BY size DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

But it's slow. Elasticsearch finds the query matches in index, but I need the index match in query. Is there any solution in elasticsearch?

Comment: Look into the full text options for MySQL.  You will need to tweak them for numbers and short strings.

Answer (score 0):

script field can be used to sort on length of text. Better option would be to also index length of text and sort on that field.

**Data:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index16",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QNLN5HEB9UrRQjNWOLGw",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "model" : "Acer Aspire 3 A315-42  aa"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index16",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QdLN5HEB9UrRQjNWQLFu",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "model" : "Acer Aspire 3 A315-42"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "model": "Acer Aspire 3 A315-42"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script":{
        "script": "doc['model.keyword'].value.length()",-->script to return length
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1 --> top 1
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index16",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QNLN5HEB9UrRQjNWOLGw",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "model" : "Acer Aspire 3 A315-42  aa"
        },
        "sort" : [
          25.0
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: You misunderstand me.
For example my query string is "acer aspire 1310 plus", and I have documents with model value "acer aspire", "acer aspire 1310", "acer aspire 1310 extra".
I want to return only the "acer aspire 1310" document, because the "acer aspire 1310" string is the longest match in the "acer aspire 1310 plus" string.

Comment: @LayAndrás You can just use match query and pick first result, it will give best match { "query": { "match": { "model": "acer aspire 1310 plus" } }, "size": 1 }

Comment: @LayAndrás does the query in the comment satisfy your requirement. I am not able to grasp your requirement